# how to get text with sed?

Tags: sed, dump

i want to grab the the text between tok98 and 5678 and dump that out to a file.

if the tok98 and the 5678 was on the same line i can use this

```
sed -n 's/.*\(tok98\)\(.*\)\(5678\).*/\2/p' testfile.txt > text.dmp
```

but when the tokens are vertically spaced its not working, how can i rewrite this sed to work here

```
$ cat testfile.txt
do with > 9
tok98
  fdf  df s df sd f sd v
  dvsdv  dvf sd vs vs dv  sdfsd

    2323 2323  232 {}   
   sfdf sd  f s df s df  sf 
5678
no way = true + 50

$
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use /START/,/STOP/ [pattern ranges](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-29) in sed

```
sed -n '/tok98/,/5678/p' file
```

/START/ and /STOP/ can be REs too

```
sed -n '/^tok98/,/^5678/p' file
```

would print between the lines starting `tok98` and `5678` and would not start or stop unless the lines begin with those strings.

If you want to exclude the /START/ and /STOP/ then this should work

```
sed -n '/^tok98/,/^5678/ {/^tok98/b;/^5678/b;p}' file
```

Answer (score 5):

`sed` by default does not process multiple lines, but this can be solved using a trick like:

```
$ cat testfile.txt | tr '\n' ',' | sed -n 's/.*\(tok98\)\(.*\)\(5678\).*/\2/p' | tr ',' '\n' > text.dmp
```

You just need to convert the newlines `\n` to some other character like `,` and then convert them back to \n when done with `sed`. You need to make sure that you input file does not have any comma.